# Matching All the Columns Have the Same Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set as follows:

```
Col1 | COl2  | Col3
--------------------
A    | Jan-1 |   1
-------------------
A    | Jan-2 |   2
-------------------
A    | Jan-3 |   2
-------------------
A    | Jan-4 |   3
-------------------
B    | Jan-1 |   1
-------------------
B    | Jan-2 |   1
-------------------
B    | Jan-3 |   1
-------------------
B    | Jan-4 |   1
-------------------
```

I want to select all the Col1 entities that have the same Col3 value for entire date range available in Col2.

Would you be able to help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can test that all the `col3` values are the same for a given `col1` value a simple `group by` and `having` query:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having min(col3) = max(col3);
```

I don't see what `col2` has to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a SP for this... For example

```
CREATE PROC your_procedure
@param1
@param2
@param3

AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Col1 = @param1 AND Col2 = @param2 AND Col3 = @param3


END
```